# Apache will not start with mod_wsgi enabled

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, python, mod-wsgi, zend-server

I'm trying to run Apache with mod_wsgi to run Python scripts. The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 with Zend Server installed, but when I enable the wsgi module Apache will not start. I get an error message of `apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed` in the error log. I installed the module using the Debian package.

I can't seem to find this specific problem anywhere so maybe it's a problem with Zend Server? I'm stumped.

Comment: _I get an error message of `apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed` in the error log._ --> please post some lines around this error?

Comment: @quanta `Starting web server apache2
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for <hostname>
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
   ...done.`

That is the entire entry in the error log.

Comment: That warning can generally be ignored.

Comment: I would normally agree, but it's the only output I'm able to find when I enable the module, and Apache will not start.

Comment: Run 'apachectl -t' to see if Apache outputs any error messages to the terminal where you run that command. Sometimes if you have missing symbols when it loads up it can silently not start but running '-t' will show you the problem.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for <hostname>
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK`

That's the whole output.

Comment: Are you running with some really odd SELinux configuration?